# Flicker fusion threshold for insect eyes

Tags: eyes, visual-system

I searched on [bio-numbers](http://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/search.aspx?log=y&task=searchbytrmorg&trm=flicker+fusion+&time=2014/12/02+03:46:43.943) for flicker-fusion threshold of insect eyes in general and for flies in particular. [Ruck, 1961](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1539540) gives values for some flies. Is there any database maintained for these values? Is there any comparative study done for many flies/insects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The flicker fusion frequencies of six laboratory insects, and the response of the compound eye to mains fluorescent ‘ripple’" ([Miall, 1978](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-3032.1978.tb00139.x/abstract)) touches on flicker fusion thresholds for six different insect species commonly used in laboratory settings:

> *Locusta migratoria*, *Periplaneta americana*, *Saturnia pavonia*, *Antheraea pernyi*, *Glossina morsitans* and *Drosophila hydei*.

I also found this paper: Potential Biological and Ecological Effects of Flickering Artificial Light ([Boyles, 2014](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4038456/)) that includes an exhaustive literature search of flicker-fusion thresholds and other related data for many species (including insects). If you're looking for an authoritative source, I'd say that this is it (as there doesn't seem to be a database with this information).